# sps3:// The object was not found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, people-search

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Search Issue
2 WFEs
3 APP servers
2 Distributed Cache Servers

We are trying to crawl sps3://mysites.mydomain.com and we get the following error in the crawl log:

**The object was not found. ( SearchID = 7425D17F-D290-453D-ABCF-B0A26E77E7BE )**

I did search for the search ID in the ULS log and found the following results:

09/30/2014 14:34:33.90  mssdmn.exe (0x33AC)                         0x4E64  SharePoint Server Search        Connectors:HTTP                 du4s    Medium      CHttpAccessorHelper::InitRequestInternal - Request/Response succeeded CorrelationID  URL http://mysites.mydomain.com/_vti_bin/spscrawl.asmx SearchRequestTime 3688, SPRequestDuration 0, SPIISLatency 0, dwStatusCode 404, hr 0x80041201  [httpacchelper.cxx:586]  search\native\gather\protocols\http\httpacchelper.cxx    7425d17f-d290-453d-abcf-b0a26e77e7be
09/30/2014 14:34:33.90  mssdmn.exe (0x33AC)                         0x4E64  SharePoint Server Search        Connectors:HTTP                 du54    High        CHttpAccessorHelper::InitRequestInternal - unexpected status (404) on request for 'http://mysites.mydomain.com/_vti_bin/spscrawl.asmx' Authentication 1.  [httpacchelper.cxx:712]  search\native\gather\protocols\http\httpacchelper.cxx    7425d17f-d290-453d-abcf-b0a26e77e7be
09/30/2014 14:34:33.90  mssdmn.exe (0x33AC)                         0x4E64  SharePoint Server Search        Connectors:HTTP                 du30    High        CHttpProbeHelper::ProbeServer: InitRequest failed for 'http://mysites.mydomain.com/_vti_bin/spscrawl.asmx'. Return error to caller, hr=80041201  [stscommon.cxx:522]  search\native\gather\protocols\common\stscommon.cxx   7425d17f-d290-453d-abcf-b0a26e77e7be
09/30/2014 14:34:33.90  mssdmn.exe (0x33AC)                         0x4E64  SharePoint Server Search        Connectors:People               duv5    High        CMatrixCache::GetSite: Probing url 'http://mysites.mydomain.com' failed. Return error to caller, hr=80041201  [matrixutil.cxx:96]  search\native\gather\protocols\sps2\matrixutil.cxx   7425d17f-d290-453d-abcf-b0a26e77e7be

Please note the following:
1. User profile is working fine. (Default content access account has Retrieve People Data For Search Crawlers)
2. http://mysites.mydomain.com crawled successfully.
3. Added **BackConnectionHostNames** registry and added web application urls (mysites.mydomain.com)
4. Added SharePoint URLs to your server’s HOSTS file
5. mysites.mydomain.com exists in SharePoint 2010 production environment and that is one of the reasons I had to do step 4, since both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 are in the same domain.
6. Windows firewall on all SharePoint Servers is disabled.

Any ideas on how to resolve/troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue using this article:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2007/03/19/crawling-sharepoint-sites-using-the-sps3-protocol-handler.aspx

The above article mentioned WFEs and since I added SharePoint URLs to your server’s HOSTS file to point to itself, I had to modify the entry on the application server that has the crawl component to point to one of the web front end instead of itself and that resolved the issue. To be clear about the resolution:

HOSTS file on Search Crawler Server before the modification:

**# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

## 127.0.0.1       localhost

## ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1    mysites.mydomain.com**

HOSTS file on Search Crawler Server after the modification (notice the IP address points to one of the web front end:

**# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

## 127.0.0.1       localhost

## ::1             localhost

192.168.150 .100    mysites.mydomain.com**